# Удаление родительской сущности, имеющей дочерние сущности в Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть две сущности, условно:

```
create table A(
    id bigserial primary key,
    ...
),

create table B(
    ...
    foreign key (b_id) references A (id)
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы была возможность удалять родительскую сущность, оставляя дочерние? В документации решения найти не получилось

Comment: вы не можете просто удалить, вам придётся изменять поля дочерней таблицы, так как она связана с родительской и если её удалить, дочь загрустит. Сначала измените дочернюю, чтобы она не ссылалась на родительскую и удаляйте.

Comment: Либо вообще не делайте ограничение внешнего ключа, то есть удалите реляцию либо почитаете про варианты действий при событиях `ON DELETE` `ON UPDATE`: `SET NULL` `SET DEFAULT` в описании команды `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: ЗЫ: Это конечно зависит от прикладной задачи которая здесь не описана, но вы должны понимать что такой подход приводит к формированию несвязанных данных в дочерних таблицах, нарушающих структурную целостность схемы данных. Если эти данные действительно нужны рассмотрите вариант переноса в параллельную зеркальную структуру для удаленных данных.

Comment: Рассмотрите также вариант организации "мягкого удаления".

Comment: @Akina, вы имеете ввиду помечать записи флагом удаления вместо самого удаления?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Угу, оно самое. Я не знаю предметной области, но в некоторых за одно намерение написать код, который удалит запись, уже надо давать по шее...